# Different Simplifaction Operation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

I tried to write a program about a different simplification operator in Ruby. I have to find numbers `(ab / bc) = a / c` when a, b, c are digits and bc > ab. For example: `16 / 64 = 1 / 4`.

Here's my code :

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1 
num1 = 10*a + b
num2 = 10*b + c

while b < 9 && c < 9
  b += 1
  num1 += 1
  num2 = num2 + 10 
  while num2 > num1
    c +=1 
    num2 += 1
    while a < 9 
      a += 1
      num1 = num1 + 10
      if (num1 / num2) == (a / c)
        puts "#{a} / #{b}"
      end
   end
end
end
```

I should reach 16/64, 19/95, 26/65 and 49/98 but instead, Ruby gives me 2/2, 3/2, 5/2, 7/2 and 9/2. What's wrong with my Code? I'm only allowed to do this with while loop. So, no other methods.

Comment: btw I can't use string variables.

Comment: Where does `10*a + b` / `10*b + c` come from?

Comment: I define it as ab / bc. When it's divided, if the answer is equals to a / c , I should reach an output: ab / bc .

Comment: Can you give an example for `a`, `b` and `c` where `ab / bc` is **not** equal to `a / c`?

Comment: while a = 1 b = 2 c = 1 ab / bc = 12 / 21, if simplified: 4 / 7. In that example 12 / 21 is not equal to 1 / 1 . But if a = 2 b = 6 c = 5 , ab / bc = 26 / 65, simplified 2 / 5. It also equal to a /c which is 2/5.

Comment: Oh I see! `ab` isn't `a * b` but the _concatenation_ of `a` and `b`. Sorry that wasn't clear to me. Now `10*` makes a lot more sense :-)

Comment: I have to do 10*a + b, because I am not allowed to use string variables. Sorry, I couldn't explain myself well

Comment: @elixir : Why don't you output (for debugging) the values of `c`, `num1` and `num2` after each modification? This should lead you to find the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would have written it:

```
(1..9).each do |a|
  (1..9).each do |b|
    (1..9).each do |c|
      ab = 10*a + b
      bc = 10*b + c
      next if bc <= ab || (ab.to_f / bc) != (a.to_f / c)

      puts "#{ab} / #{bc} == #{a} / #{c}"
    end
  end
end

# Result:
# 16 / 64 == 1 / 4
# 19 / 95 == 1 / 5
# 26 / 65 == 2 / 5
# 49 / 98 == 4 / 8
```

Note my use of `to_f` - which is important because if you just try to divide integers, you get an integer answer (e.g. `3/2 == 1`, but `3.to_f/2 == 1.5`).

---

What's wrong with your solution? Well aside from the aforementioned integer division issue (which is why your results are clearly incorrect), there are a few problems.

For one thing, you're immediately incrementing the values of `a`, `b` and `c` in the loops, so you never actually test for cases where they are equal to 1. (This is why all your results start with `b == 2`.)

Also, this inner loop is buggy:

```
while a < 9 
  a += 1
  # ...
```

...because by changing the value of `a`, you also may have invalidated the assumption that `num2 > num1`. (This is why your results contain improper fractions.)

Next, your overall strategy of using `while` loops is flawed: You're never setting `c` or `a` back to `1` -- so you're actually failing to loop over the majority of possible values for `(a, b, c)`. (This is why most valid answers are missing.)

...And on top of that, you're printing the wrong thing!! The question was to find all numbers where `ab / bc == a / c`, but you're printing `a / b` - so of course it's going to be wrong

---

Moral of the story: Learn how to use a [debugger](https://github.com/pry/pry), think carefully about what logical flow you've written, and maybe try building up from a simpler base case (e.g. fix `a == 1`) before expanding into the whole logic

Comment: BTW I'm assuming `a, b, c != 0`, and you didn't want to include silly results like: `10 / 0 == 1 / 0`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but this is my homework for school and we don't learn methods like next, or .each. That why I'm struggling. I'm only allowed to do this with  if and while. You're right about my code, it's full of mistakes but I'm a beginner and I try to learn :)))

Comment: The problem is perfectly solvable using `while`, but you might find it a bit harder... Nevertheless, hopefully my comments above should point out some issues with your first attempt!

Comment: ...Although for what it's worth, unless your teacher has explicitly asked for you to *only use `while` loops* (??!!), you shouldn't feel obligated to stick to such a tiny subset of the language!

Comment: If I use something different than while loop my homework will be considered as invalid:( So I had no other choice. I really liked your version by the way, thank you. Is there any alternative thing to .each do ? What I'm trying to do is increment digits as you did. But I can't make it with while-loop.

Comment: It is possible to write a very similar solution to my answer above, using a `while` loop. But you need to think a bit more about how to ensure **all** possible values of `a`, `b` and `c` are being looped over.

Comment: Hint: Maybe start by just trying to print all possible values (a, b, c) for the range 1-3, i.e. (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 1), ........

Comment: Thanks, will try !

Comment: `ab.to_f / bc` can be rewritten as `ab.fdiv(bc)`. And there's even a "lossless" variant: `ab.quo(bc)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Oh, whoops... I think I wrote that answer before spotting the silly `a/b` vs `a/c` typo in OP's original version of the `puts` statement. So yeah, my logic was sound but my *original* output was wrong. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Stefan, I'd never seen `Numeric#quo`, so I figured it was newish, but no, it's ancient.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is very complex, so I find it quite hard to follow. In fact, I don't understand it at all.

There are a couple of things I noticed that may or may not explain your problems.

You are initializing all three digits to 1, then immediately increment them at the *beginning* of the loop. That means, you will never get any solutions that include 1, such as 16/64 = 1/4. Either initialize the variables to 0 or move the increment to the end of the loop. (Either way, make sure you don't screw up the exit conditions that way!)

Also, you are more or less incrementing all of them at the same time in a single loop, whereas you actually want three *nested* iterations where you try (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), and so on, instead of (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), …

You are using integer division throughout your code. But in integer division, for example, `12/23 == 0` and `1/3 == 0`, therefore `12/23 == 1/3` and will thus be counted as a valid solution. Personally, I would use rational numbers instead.

Also, this looks fishy: `b < 9 && b < 9`.

Here is a solution that somewhat resembles yours. I tried to fix your code, but I just couldn't understand how it works, I am just not clever enough.

```ruby
a = 0

while (a += 1) < 10
  b = 0

  while (b += 1) < 10
    c = 0

    while (c += 1) < 10
      r = Rational(10*a + b, 10*b + c)
      puts "#{a}#{b}/#{b}#{c} = #{a}/#{c} = #{r}" if r < 1 && r == Rational(a, c)
    end
  end
end
```

Personally, I would write something like this:

```ruby
DIGITS = (1..9).to_a.freeze

results = DIGITS.repeated_permutation(3).
  select do |a, b, c|
    r = Rational(10*a + b, 10*b + c)
    r < 1 && r == Rational(a, c)
  end.
  map {|a, b, c| %W[#{a}#{b}/#{b}#{c} #{a}/#{c} #{Rational(a, c)}].join(' = ') }

puts results
# 16/64 = 1/4 = 1/4
# 19/95 = 1/5 = 1/5
# 26/65 = 2/5 = 2/5
# 49/98 = 4/8 = 1/2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I can't solve how can I increment digits with just using while-loop. Your code is short and effective but I don't really know the methods. I should do this with while loop and if. Btw b < 9 && b < 9 part is escaped from my attention, sorry.  Where should I use the digits for incrementing them step by step?

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be simplified and made more efficient by turning the problem on its head, looping through values of `a/c` rather than those of `ab/bc`.

First observe that when `ab/bc = a/c`, `bc > ab` if and only if `c > a`. We therefore may write the following.

```
(1..8).each do |a|
  (a+1..9).each do |c|
    r = Rational(a,c)
    (1..9).each do |b|
      num, denom = 10*a + b, 10*b + c
      puts "#{num}\/#{denom} = #{a}\/#{c}" if Rational(num, denom) == r
    end
  end
end
```

which displays

```
16/64 = 1/4
19/95 = 1/5
26/65 = 2/5
49/98 = 4/8
```